# C Basic Head Command

Tags: c, linux, tail, head

I'm trying to recreate the head, and tail commands from linux for my programming class.
We just started using C so I'm new to the idea of allocating memory and pointers.
I'm wondering why this doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv){

    /* Checks if correct amount of arguements */

    if(argc != 2 || argc != 4){
        printf("Usage: %s head <file> \n Or: head <file> -n <number of characters>", argv[0]);
        exit(-1);
    }

    if(strcmp(argv[1], "-n" != 0)){
        char fileName[strlen(argv[1])] = argv[1];
    }
}

//Compile error on char fileName[strlen(argv[1])] = argv[1];
```

Any additional insight would also be helpful.

Comment: `fileName` is also only visible inside its enclosing block, in this case the affirmative branch of the `if` statement.

Comment: You're only ever going to see the usage message, because if `argc` is equal to 2, it is not equal to 4, and if it is equal to 4, it is not equal to 2, and if it is neither 2 nor 4, then...

Comment: Did you specify `-std=c99` on the GCC command line?  You still need to do that to get the compiler to accept a VLA (variable-length array).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first, your usage doesn't match your argument checking. According to the usage, you must use one of:

```
head <filename>
head <filename> -n <count>
```

In other words, `argv[1]` is *always* the filename, `argv[2]` is the one that needs to be set to `-n` if there are more than two arguments.

Secondly, unless you want to use VLAs (variable length arrays), you should probably just set up a pointer to the filename argument with something like:

```
char *fileName = argv[1];
```

You don't need to change it at all (you'll just be passing it to `fopen`, presumably), so it's a waste trying to make another copy.

In addition, your `if` statement is wrong as an `or`, it should be an `and`. It's guaranteed that `argc` will either not be 2 or not be 4, since it can't be both at the same time.

I would start with something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int usage (void) {
    printf ("Usage: head <file>\n");
    printf ("   or: head <file> -n <number of characters>\n");
    return -1;
}

int main (int argc,char *argv[]) {
    char *fileName;
    int lineCount;

    // Checks if correct arguments

    if ((argc != 2) && (argc != 4)) return usage();

    if ((argc == 4) && (strcmp(argv[2], "-n" != 0)) return usage();

    // Get file spec and line count

    fileName = argv[1];

    lineCount = (argc == 2) ? 10 : atoi (argv[3]); // or strtol for purists
    if (linecount < 0) lineCount = 0;

    // Now go ahead and implement the logic for head.

}
```

Comment: and note that with this approach `fileName` is _not_ a deep copy of argv[1] - it's just a pointer that shares its contents with argv[1].  This is OK since argv[] is usually never deallocated.  In other situations, this is one of the "gotchas" of C.

Comment: "Usually" never deallocated? I would say "never", at least not until after `main` returns (or your program exits some other way).

Answer (score 3):

I think it's better to write:

```
char fileName[strlen(argv[1])+1];
strcpy(fileName, argv[1]);
```

or (if you don't whant to make a copy of string) :

```
char* fileName = argv[1];
```

Comment: There's really no point in making a copy of an argument unless you're going to modify the copy, so your second suggestion is much more sensible.

Comment: It depends on situation isn't it? Author tried to make a copy for some reason, so, may be he made it with purpose and he want to modify this string somewhere...

Comment: In the code for `head`, the most plausible use for the file name is to open it, and for that, you don't need the copy (the original should do).  You're right that in some circumstances, there is a need to copy and edit the name.  For example, if you've got some sort of 'compiler', you might want to change the extension of the input file to specify the output file.  If so, then making a copy of the whole string and editing the copy is a good idea because you also still need the input file name for things like the open call and error reporting.

Comment: I'm not sure that Ostap Hnatyuk publish final version of his main(...). May be next improovment of his app is to use multiple threads which will require private copy of "file name" string for per each thread. Anyway, you can't be sure what author want to do with this string. BTW, I wrote two solutions, both solutions will work properly.