# C Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, linux, file, fopen, head

Hi sorry for all the questions, but I am getting a "Segmentation fault(core dumped)" on my terminal window when I run this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int usage (void) {
    printf("Usage: head <file>\n");
    printf("   Or: head <file> -n <number of characters>\n");
    printf("   Or: head -n <number of characters> <file>\n"); 
    return -1;
}

int main (int argc,char **argv) {
    if ((argc != 2) && (argc != 4)) return usage();

    char *fileName = argv[1];
    int lineCount = 10;
    FILE *src;

    if ((argc == 4) && (strcmp(argv[1], "-n" != 0))){
        fileName = argv[1];
        lineCount = argv[3]; 
        puts("-n in last position");
    }else{
        fileName = argv[3];
        lineCount = argv[1];
        puts("-n in first position");
    }

    if((src = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL){
        puts("Can't open input file.");
        exit(-1);
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure it's with the fopen function, but I'm not exactly sure why this is happening.

Comment: Also I don't know why the code formatted in this so terribly, so sorry for that.

Comment: Code formatting: avoid tabs and pre-format the code with tabstops set at 4 spaces for most comfortable formatting on SO.  (`pr -e4 -l1 -t` is a suitable command on Linux; there may be others.)

Comment: You will need to convert the numeric argument string using `atoi()` or something similar — not by assigning a pointer to the integer.  Pay attention to your compiler's warnings!

Comment: If this is homework, you should add the homework tag.

Answer (score 6):

it looks like if argc==2 you immediately access argv[3].  That's gotta hurt.

Comment: I think this is causing the segmentation fault. But a complete answer should include the problems found by @AndrianCornish

Comment: You're right — it is definitely undefined behaviour.  In practice, you'll often find that `argv[argc+1]` is the first environment variable, but you most certainly can't depend on that in portable code.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few things wrong first off - the comparison is inside the function

```
strcmp(argv[1], "-n" != 0)
```

You are assigning an char * to a int

```
lineCount = argv[3];
```

And here

```
lineCount = argv[1];
```

Here are the compile errors I get

```
[adrian@iceweasel ~]$ gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic uu.c
uu.c: In function ‘main’:
uu.c:15: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code
uu.c:19: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘strcmp’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/string.h:143: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
uu.c:21: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
uu.c:25: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
uu.c:33: warning: control reaches end of non-void function
```

Answer (score 1):

You have one of the closing parentheses in the wrong place:

```
(strcmp (argv[1], "-n" != 0))
```

should be:

```
(strcmp (argv[1], "-n") != 0)
```

However, even once that's fixed, your argument processing is still not quite right.

In [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361558/c-basic-head-command), the `head -n COUNT FILE` was not a possibility, that made the argument checking reasonably easy.

Here's the logic you need to follow now that you allow for a "floating" `-n count` section:

```
int linecount
char *filename = NULL

if argc == 2:
    linecount = 10
    filename = argv[1]
else:
    if argc == 4:
        if argv[1] == "-n":
            linecount = argv[2]
            filename = argv[3]
        else:
            if argv[2] == "-n":
                linecount = argv[3]
                filename = argv[1]

if filename = NULL:
    generate some error
```

It basically catches the two-argument version first. If it's a four-argument version, it then finds out where the "-n" is so it can intelligently decide which argument is which value.

As you can see, that's not quite what you have (your code looks for linecount in `argv[1]` which is *never* the case). You should use something like this as a guide:

```
argc  argv[0]  argv[1]  argv[2]  argv[3]
----  -------  -------  -------  -------
   2  head     <file>
   4  head     <file>   -n       <count>
   4  head     -n       <count>  <file>
```

Once you refer to that, it should be easy to write the code for the different situations.

You'll have to turn that pseudo-code of mine back into C of course (using `strcmp` instead of `==` for strings, and ensuring you use `atoi/strtol` for converting the string linecount argument to an integer), but that's the basic flow you should follow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use the `getopt()` function?  On Linux, the `getopt()` function would handle the `-n` option in either location with aplomb (unless the `POSIXLY_CORRECT` environment variable is set).  It would make life easier for you:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int numLines = 10;
    char *fileName = 0;
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "n:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'n':
            numLines = atoi(optarg);  /* Could check for positive answer */
            break;
        default:
            usage();  /* Assuming usage() does not return */
            break;
        }
    }

    if (optind != argc - 1)  /* Insist on one filename argument */
        usage();

    fileName = argv[optind];

    ...open file and process it...

    return(0);
}
```

Note that it would be easy to process standard input instead of a file; the condition after the loop would need to be adjusted, of course. You can also easily add a `-?` or `-h` option for help, and so on.